# Two websites on server with two public IPs Ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ip

I've bought a VPS witch has 2 public IP addresses assigned to it.

I want to configure Apache so I can have two different sites (in separated directories), each one available from a different public IP.

Comment: And your question is ...?

Comment: Do you have any control panel on your VPS or its a plain VPS without any control panel ?

Comment: It has no control panel, I've root access via SSH.

Comment: I've configured Apache before for using SSL and listening to different ports, so maybe I'm just missing a config line?

Comment: Not to be too mean, but this is covered extensively in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) and any number of tutorials. Server Fault is a site for professionals, and part of being a professional is reading the documentation.  If you've done what the docs say and are still having a problem, please ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to configure Apache for hosting two websites in two different IP address. This is whats called IP based virtual hosting. for this you need configure the both ipaddress in apache2.conf file with Listen Directive.

```
Listen 192.168.1.20:80
Listen 192.168.1.21:80
```

After restarting you can see that apache is listening on both IPs by applying netstat -ntlp.

Regards